# Should I use the Main method in my C# program or the reader method to create my list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, program-entry-point

I am working on a project that will read data from an excel sheet, put each row into a class called "Sale" and then manipulate the list in the future. Should I add the sales into the list in the class that I am using to read the excel document, titled "Reader", or should I create the list in the Main class and method. I currently have my main method creating an instance of the Reader. This reader then passes the rows, or "Sales" through a modifier which will sort them. Then a printer class takes the list as a parameter and prints it onto the same workbook on a different document.

Will doing one or the other make any significant difference in my program? If so why and which is better in terms of efficiency and organization.

Comment: `Sales` should probably be a separate class that maintains a list of `Sale` items. You can then add methods to manipulate the list inside that class. The `Reader` method should just be that. It retrieves excel data that you would use to create a `Sale` object, then use the `Sales.Add()` method to add it to the list.

Comment: If `Sale` represents row data then it should be separate from its storage. You can have `List<Sale> sales` and `Reader` will do `sales.Add(sale)`. This way the storage implementation can change (queue or stack) without changing the Sale class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Deolus in reference to `Sales` being its own class.

Keep `Sales` and `Reader` separate because they have different purposes.  If the `Reader` class was created to solely read data from an excel sheet then that should be its only objective.  In the `Sales` class you can create additional methods to manipulate the list of sales in the future.

---

***Will doing one or the other make any significant difference in my program?***

In terms of speed when running the program this will not make a difference, but in terms of maintainability this is **GOLD**.

This is a perfect example of [separation of concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns).  The better you keep your code organized and not mangled spaghetti code, the more efficient and effective you will be when it comes time to maintain this code in the future.  So, the *significant difference* will be when you have to maintain & sustain this in the future.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky question since you don't define your later action/classes you work with.
If you'll have another class to work on that data, it might be better to wipe the instance of your reader class from your memory.
Keeping the list in your main class however might be bad too, it is important to know if you pass by value or by reference here for example. Having your reader class pass values, having your main class save those values and pass them to your work class might be bad for cpu (as this takes more steps) and memory since you create copies - and maybe you don't need the data in your main class anymore after passing it.

What counts in on efficiency too is hard drive space (although nobody cares about that, in terms of small applications it isn't significant after all) - less code taking less of your hard drive often is more intense on memory and/or cpu.

Your question is generally to vague to explicitly say what's more efficient, but you also have to notice, that code optimization is to enhance existing code, not to build code itself in the first place.